# Measurability of multifunctions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

If $(T,\mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space , $X$ a meatrizable separable space.

$F$ a multifunction from $T$ to compacte subsets of $X$.

We want to prove that $F$ is measurable if

$\forall U\in X$ ,$U$ open,$F^{-1}_+(U)=\lbrace t\in T; F(t)\cap U\neq \emptyset\rbrace \in \mathcal{A}$

In my book they say :

Remark that : $F^{-1}_+(U)=F^{-1}_+(\lbrace K \in \mathcal{P}_K(X); K\cap U \neq \emptyset \rbrace)$

($\mathcal{P}_K(X)$ is the space of all compact sets of $X$)

My question is : why we have : $F^{-1}_+(U)=F^{-1}_+(\lbrace K \in \mathcal{P}_K(X); K\cap U \neq \emptyset \rbrace)$

Please

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t \in F^{-1}_+(U)$ iff $F(t) \cap U \neq \emptyset$. Since $F(t)$ is compact for all $t \in T$, we have that $t \in F^{-1}_+(U)$ iff $F(t) \in \{ K \in \mathcal P_K(\mathcal X): K \cap U \neq \emptyset \}$. Hence 
$$ F^{-1}_+(U) = F^{-1}_+(\{ K \in \mathcal P_K(\mathcal X): K \cap U \neq \emptyset \}).   $$

Comment: thank you for the answer , but please you want to say that $F(t)$ is one of $K\in \mathcal{P}_{K}(X)$

Comment: yes, as you defined $F$, $F(t)$ is a compact set.

Comment: And please why if $C$ is a closed subset in $X$ $F^{-1}_+(C)=\lbrace t, F(T)\cap C\neq\emptyset\rbrace= \mathcal{C}_{T}F^{-1}_+(\lbrace K\in \mathcal{P}_{K}(X), K\subset X-C\rbrace)$

Comment: have you an idea please ?

Comment: The complement of $F_+^{-1}(C)$ is the set of all $t$ such that $F(t) \cap C = \emptyset$, ie, all $t$ such that $F(t) \subset X \setminus C$.

Comment: ok, but why for a closed set F^{-1}(C) is the complement ,please

Comment: the statement holds for any set $C$.